# Change five module user rating text

Tags: 7, rating

I am using fivestar module to rate the content. I have added it to my view and full node view. I have configured it only to display number user voted the content. By default it is displaying as `No votes or (10 Votes)` and so on. I want to alter the text as `(0) or (10)` and so on. How can I alter the text. 
 In contrib it  is written in http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!fivestar!includes!fivestar.theme.inc/function/theme_fivestar_static/7

Answer (score 0):

You programmatically alter it via [hook_node_view_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_view_alter/7)

> This hook is called after the content has been assembled in a
>   structured array and may be used for doing processing which requires
>   that the complete node content structure has been built.